# Is there an implicit memory barrier with synchronized-with relationship on thread::join?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-barriers, memory-fences

I have a code at work that starts multiple threads that doing some operations and if any of them fail they set the shared variable to *false*.

Then main thread joins all the worker threads. Simulation of this looks roughly like this (I commented out the possible fix which I don't know if it's needed):

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

//atomic_bool success = true;
bool success = true;

int main()
{
    vector<thread> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        v.emplace_back([=]
        {
            if (i == 5 || i == 6)
            {
                //success.store(false, memory_order_release);
                success = false;
            }
        });
    }
    for (auto& t : v)
        t.join();

    //assert(success.load(memory_order_acquire) == false);
    assert(success == false);

    cout << "Finished" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a possibility that main thread will read the success variable as *true* even though one of the workers set it to *false*?

I found that *thread::join()* is a full memory barrier ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338000/does-relaxed-memory-order-effect-can-be-extended-to-after-performing-threads-li)) but does that imply **synchronized-with** relationship with the following read of *success* variable from the main thread, so that we're guaranteed to get newest value?

Is the fix I posted (in the commented code) necessary in this case (or maybe another fix if this one is wrong)?

Is there a possibility that read of *success* variable will be optimized away (since it's not volatile) and we will get old value regardless of **suppossed to exist** implicit memory barrier on *thread::join*?

**The code is suppossed to work on multiple architectures (cannot remember all of them, I don't have makefile in front of me) but there are atleast x86, amd64, itanium, arm7.**

Thanks for any help with this.

Edit: I've modified the example, because in real situation more then one thread can try to write to *success* variable.

Comment: Isn't the source clear about that? "Since thread creation and structure is defined as a synchronizing operation, joining a thread necessarily happens after that thread terminates. Thus you will see anything that necessarily happened before the thread terminated."

Comment: I'm not sure since as you can see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence reference only mentions synchronization between fences and atomic objects, there is nothing about synchronization between fences and ordinary objects. I think join uses such fence internally, but I may be wrong.

Comment: [Yes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.member#4). Otherwise `join` would be rather useless.

Comment: @T.C. isn't the multiple unsynchronised overwrite of `success` between the 5 threads technically UB?

Comment: @RichardHodges Only one thread writes to it in the example...?

Comment: @T.C. ah yes. you're right.

Comment: @RichardHodges Hi I'm sorry for this error, I've modified the example, because in real program more than one thread can try to write to *success* variable, does this change the situation?

Comment: @T.C. what about now it's been edited. Although I expect it would work, I think it's UB.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yep, clear cut nasal demons now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above represents a data race, and the use of `join` cannot change that fact. If only one thread wrote to the variable, it would be fine. But you have two threads writing to it, with *no* synchronization between them. That's a data race.

`join` simply means "all side effects of that thread's operation have completed and are now visible to you." That does not create ordering or synchronization between that thread and any thread *other* than your own.

If you used an `atomic_bool`, then it wouldn't be UB; it would be guaranteed to be false. But because there is a data race, you get pure UB. It might be true, false, or nasal demons.

Comment: Ok I get the undefined behavior part. But assuming we're on the platform where write to bool is atomic, and my thread (the one which joins all workers) is the only one reading the *success* flag, will *join* be enough to guarantee proper ordering and I will always see *false* if some worker set it or can I still get *true*?

Comment: @Mikaka: "*But assuming we're on the platform where write to bool is atomic*" No. You asked about C++. I'm telling you what C++ guarantees. How "arbitrary platform that I hope does something reasonable" behaves is a matter between you and your platform of choice. If you want this to be *guaranteed* to work, you use an actual `atomic<bool>`. If that is a platform that behaves in the way you think it does, then `atomic<bool>` will just be a thin wrapper around a `bool`. And if it doesn't, then it will still be correct.